# su: user sh does not exist

Tags: centos, sh, sudo, su

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
sudo su sh <(curl https://mirror.cyberpanel.net/install-test.sh || wget -O - https://mirror.cyberpanel.net/install-test.sh)
```

but get this output:

```
...
su: user sh does not exist
....
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8192)
.....   
Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success).
```

Can anyone help resolve?

Comment: Downloading random cr\*p from the 'nets and running it under uid 0 without any verification gives me creeps.

Comment: Please don't use `sudo su`. `sudo` says "do the following as root" and `su` says, "become root". It's the same thing, but twice. Why not just `sudo sh -c "curl ... || wget ...`"?

Comment: You're planning to run code from an external web site as root without looking at it first? Bad, bad idea.

Comment: disclaimer i'm fully informed on the code I'm running, just having trouble running it. thanks for the help and concerns

Answer (score 3):

In the command `su sh` *sh* is a user name. If you want `su` to interpret it as a command to run add option `-c`:

```
sudo su -c "sh…"
```

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/su and https://www.sudo.ws/man.html

Comment: Now i get  ....  su: user /dev/fd/63 does not exist
.....
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8192)
.......
Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success).

Comment: The option `-c` for `su` accepts only one word for command. Try `sudo su -c "sh <(curl URL)"` (note quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Save the file to disk first

```
url=https://mirror.cyberpanel.net/install-test.sh
curl -O "$url" || wget -O - "$url"
# Examine the contents of install-test.sh first, *then* run ...
sudo sh install-test.sh
```

"Examine" could me reading it yourself to verify that it doesn't do anything you don't want it to do, or comparing its MD5 checksum to an expected value.